# Get the type of an identifier with the TypeScript compiler API

Tags: typescript

Given this input file:

```
function foo (s: string) {
  console.log(s)
}
```

I want to programmatically determine the type of `s` in `console.log(s)`. In other words, I want to use whatever mechanism VSCode is using to tell me that `s` is a string when I hover over it.

[image: screenshot of VSCode]

This is as close as I've gotten.

```js
const ts = require("typescript");

const sourceCode = `
function (s: string) {
  console.log(s)
}
`;

const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
  "test.ts",
  sourceCode,
  ts.ScriptTarget.Latest
);

const functionDeclaration = sourceFile.statements[0];

const identifier =
  functionDeclaration.body.statements[0].expression.arguments[0]; // the s in console.log(s)

const typeChecker = ts.createTypeChecker(ts.createProgram(["test.ts"], {}));
const type = typeChecker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(identifier);

console.log(typeChecker.typeToString(type));
```

I'm expecting the output to be "string". Instead the output is "any".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to get the example code in the question to work, but I did find the answer I need.

Given a type node, I can call `getFlags()` which returns a bitmap. I can then mask that bitmap against `typescript.TypeFlags.Undefined` to find out if it's the `undefined` type.

In case it's a union type, I need to do the check against each of the types in `typeNode.types`.

The important code ended up looking like this:

```js
const couldBeUndefined = 
    typeNode.getFlags() & typescript.TypeFlags.Undefined || 
    typeNode.types?.some((n) => n.getFlags() & typescript.TypeFlags.Undefined);
```

This isn't working with the example code in the question, but it worked where I needed it, in an ESLint rule.